# jQuery slide left and right - simpler way to write the code?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have some jQuery which i think could be written a lot simpler, I am new to jQuery, I would also like to add a slide in and out animation to the code but not sure how best to do this. Any help would be great.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.utilTabFilter').click(function() {
    if($('#sideFilter.smallScreenFilter').css("left")=="0px")
    {
        $('#sideFilter.smallScreenFilter').css("left","-232px");    
        $('.smallScreenFilter .utilFollowFilter').css("display","none");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#sideFilter.smallScreenFilter').css("left","0");
        $('.smallScreenFilter .utilFollowFilter').css("display","block");
    }       
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your style into CSS class:

```
.myClass { left: -232px }
```

and toggle it on click. Plus use `.toggle()` method to toggle visibility:

```
$('.utilTabFilter').click(function() {
   $('#sideFilter.smallScreenFilter').toggleClass('myClass');
   $('.smallScreenFilter .utilFollowFilter').toggle();
});
```